# Newform.aspx in Office 365

Tags: list, office-365, custom-form

Is there any way so when I click "Add new item" link in a list in office 365, that will redirect to a custom new form instead of default SharePoint form?

Comment: Did you try with the Designer? Create a NewCustomForm and change the default to it

Comment: Actually my task is not design a another form, just redirect the url to custom form whatever...., Is thr any method or logic for this

Comment: Is this custom form a form of the list? Or just a page you created? If it's a list form, then you need to go to Designer and make it the default.

Comment: I am trying to programmatically do this as well for O365. i would either like to direct them to my custom newform or modify the current newform to show a custom webpart.

Answer (score 1):

On the NewForm.aspx add a Script Editor Web Part (from Media and Content) and add the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.replace(http://theListUrl/MyCustomNewForm.aspx);
</script>
```

But be careful. If you do, the only option to get it back to where it "normal" is to edit the NewForm.aspx in SharePoint Designer:

```
<WebPartPages:ScriptEditorWebPart runat="server" Content="
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;
window.location.replace(&quot;http://theListUrl/MyCustomNewForm.aspx&quot;);
&lt;/script&gt;" 
Title="Script Editor" Description="Allows authors to insert HTML snippets or scripts." 
ChromeType="None" ID="g_76a8a96c_1a2c_4f61_b1b4_6cb21575717e" 
__MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{76A8A96C-1A2C-4F61-B1B4-6CB21575717E}" 
WebPart="true" __designer:IsClosed="false" partorder="2"></WebPartPages:ScriptEditorWebPart>
```